# What does hardware virtualization extension mean?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, hyper-v

When programming againt virual machine, some system remind hardware virtualization extension is needed. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware virtualization extension allows your computer to have second state which represents virtual machine state (for example vmware). When VM code is scheduled to run, processor switches to its "virtual" context and then works in this "sandbox". When hypervisor executes guest code it needs to emulate many hardware aspects - perform software virtualiztion of them. Hardware extensions allows to do the emulation in hardware. It significantly reduces virtualization overhead.

Answer (score 0):

When a CPU is emulated (vCPU) by the hypervisor, the hypervisor has to translate the instructions meant for the vCPU to the physical CPU. As you can imagine this has a massive performance impact. To overcome this, modern processors support virtualization extensions, such as Intel VT-x and AMD-V. These technologies provide the ability for a slice of the physical CPU to be directly mapped to the vCPU. Therefore the instructions meant for the vCPU can be directly executed on the physical CPU slic